# How to set debug in Jetty started by mvn jetty:run?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, jetty

I am using `mvn jetty:run` command to build and start my java application inside embedded jetty server. How do I specify the java debug port for remote debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remote debug my application by setting the `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`, before running `mvn jetty:run`